# Unable to get the new time

Tags: java

I've the below Java code.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String startFormattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(startFormattedDate);
Thread.sleep(10000L);
String endFormattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(endFormattedDate);
```

Here basically what I'm trying to achieve is, print the current time, wait for 10 seconds and then print the time again. But to my surprise, the console is printing the same time after 10 seconds. Please let me know how can I get the time after waiting for 10 seconds. Since I need to do some calculations based on both the times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using always the same `Date` instance. To achieve what you want you need a new instance of Date

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String startFormattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(startFormattedDate);
Thread.sleep(10000L);
Date after10Seconds = new Date(); //here
String endFormattedDate = sdf.format(after10Seconds);
System.out.println(endFormattedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the same variable date is used. It is showing the same data after 10 seconds as well. You need to reinitialize it after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `Date` object after timeout to get the current time:

```
String endFormattedDate = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Certainly, you may add up `10000 ms` to the previous time and get an analogical
result without timeout:

```
Date current = new Date(date.getTime() + 10000);
String endFormattedDate = sdf.format(current);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you make only one instance of Date() at the beginning. Try to do this after you print your start date.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat edf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String endFormattedDate = edf.format(date);
System.out.println(endFormattedDate);
```